# sonarqube 6.3 error could-not-complete-symbolic-execution-reached-limit-of-16000 steps

Tags: java, sonarqube, try-catch-finally

We have a scan that aborts on the code below, with the exception:

```
org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker$MaximumStepsReachedException: reached limit of 16000 steps for method getServiceProviders#151 in class ServiceProviderService
```

We looked at rules S2259 and S2583 and would like to keep notifications about null pointers.

This happens in both "regular" and debug (-X) mode, so it's not issue 1406.  In our case it really seems to be related to try/catch.  (See sample method below.)  Could it be a resurgence of issue 1295?  https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1295   If so, is there a way to simply increase the stack from 16,000 so that we can move along?

## SAMPLE METHOD:

```
public static List<ServiceProvider> getServiceProviders() throws DAOException {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    List<ServiceProvider> serviceProviderList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        con = DatabaseUtils.getConnection();
        if (con != null) {
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(sqlSelectServiceProviders);

            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                ServiceProvider serviceProvider = new ServiceProvider();
                serviceProvider.setId(rs.getLong(1));
                serviceProvider.setName(rs.getString(2));
                // etc.
                serviceProviderList.add(serviceProvider);
            }   
        } else {
            DAOException ourDAOException = new DAOException();
            ourDAOException.setMessageCode(Consts.ERROR_CANNOT_ESTABLISH_CONNECTIONS);
            throw ourDAOException;
        }   
    } catch (DAOException daoexcep) {
        throw daoexcep;

    } catch (Exception sqlex) {
        log.error(ErrorType.SYSTEM + ": " + Consts.ERROR_CANNOT_GET_SERVICE_PROVIDER + " - " + sqlex);
        log.error(sqlex);
        try {
            if (con != null) {
                con.rollback();
            }   
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        }   
        DAOException ourDAOException = new DAOException(sqlex);
        ourDAOException.setMessageCode(Consts.ERROR_CANNOT_GET_SERVICE_PROVIDER);
        throw ourDAOException;
    } finally {
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }   
            con = null;
        }   
    }   
    return serviceProviderList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

6.3 and later require Oracle Java 8.  Our public Java 7 seems to be the most likely culprit.  The actual cause might have been something else, but the upgrade fixed it.